# Change color of a single specific citation within \citep

Tags: latex

I have to submit a revised paper with several new references. Those must be highlighted in the color blue. What I want to accomplish is that only **those** citations are colored in blue in a \citep environment, for instance:

```
\citep{a, b, c}
```

Here I just want **'b'** in the color blue. I tried with \color command, and the hyperref package, but it seems that they just effect global changes.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new command

```
\newcommand{\citeColored}[2]{\hypersetup{citecolor=#1}\cite{#2}\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}}
```

and in your document, use it as

```
 \citeColored{yellow}{eg}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same problem when I was working on a revised manuscript. One of the reviewers asked me to include more recent works along with another citation that I initially put there. To distinguish the ones I added later in the revision, I did the following:

- Originial tex:
  `some text \citep{a} and more text`.
- Revised tex:
  `some text (\citealp{a}; \textcolor{orange}{\citealp{b,c,d}}) more text`.

1. The `\citealp{a}` **does not show the parentheses**, which allowed me to add them manually (before the original and after the new citations) to make all citations appear to be a single compound list of citations.
2. The `\textcolor{orange}` is a standard function from `xcolor`. I used orange for all my revised text.
3. Besides the paranetheses, I also manually inserted a **semi-colon** and **a space** between original and new citations to make them look consistent.